# How to Display List Data with ListView from SQLite without by clicking button on my case?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

i'm just need small change with my simple project, in my Class to retrive data from Sqlite with ListView by Clicking `btnDisplay`, 
and i'm just need without by clicking, when i'm running my class, and just show `"id","Nama_Gedung"`, the logic it is same with this old code, but just need without Clicking `btnDisplay`

so what should i do with my code?, thank you so much before.

```
public class MainParkirDalam extends ListActivity  implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Button btnAdd,btnGetAll, btnClose;
    TextView parkirdalam_Id;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view== findViewById(R.id.btnAdd)){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ParkirDalamDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("parkirdalam_Id",0);

            startActivity(intent);

        }else {

            ParkirDalamRepo repo = new ParkirDalamRepo(this);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parkirdalamList =  repo.getParkirDalamList();
            if(parkirdalamList.size()!=0) {
                ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                        parkirdalam_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parkirdalam_Id);
                        String parkirdalamId = parkirdalam_Id.getText().toString();
                        Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ParkirDalamDetail.class);
                        objIndent.putExtra("parkirdalam_Id", Integer.parseInt( parkirdalamId));
                        startActivity(objIndent);
                    }
                });
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainParkirDalam.this,parkirdalamList, R.layout.view_parkirdalam_entry, new String[] { "id","Nama_Gedung"}, new int[] {R.id.parkirdalam_Id, R.id.nama_gedung});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Tidak Ada Area Parkir Dalam",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

           if (view== findViewById(R.id.btnClose)){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainMenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parkir_dalam);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnGetAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetAll);
        btnGetAll.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Parkir_dalam_actvity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tambah"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnGetAll"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnGetAll" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnAdd" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tampilkan"
        android:id="@+id/btnGetAll"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Keluar"
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnGetAll"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGetAll"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnGetAll" />

</RelativeLayout>

}
```

View_ParkirDalam_Entry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parkirdalam_Id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nama_gedung"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why can't you move all the code that happens when you click the button into onCreate?

Comment: If you put your code directly in the onCreate method, he will be executed when the view is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This chunk of code can go at the bottom of `onCreate`, though, you might still want a button event because it would make sense if you want to update the ListView at a later point in time. In that case, the last few lines of this should be made a `loadListViewFromDatabase()` method, for example.

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        parkirdalam_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parkirdalam_Id);
        String parkirdalamId = parkirdalam_Id.getText().toString();
        Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ParkirDalamDetail.class);
        objIndent.putExtra("parkirdalam_Id", Integer.parseInt( parkirdalamId));
        startActivity(objIndent);
    }
});

// loadListViewFromDatabase()
ParkirDalamRepo repo = new ParkirDalamRepo(this);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parkirdalamList =  repo.getParkirDalamList();
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainParkirDalam.this,parkirdalamList, R.layout.view_parkirdalam_entry, 
      new String[] { "id","Nama_Gedung"}, 
      new int[] {R.id.parkirdalam_Id, R.id.nama_gedung});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Yeah, I never said delete the onClick, just you can move that code

Comment: Hey Cricket_007, could you help my brother on this questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798161/how-to-store-and-retrive-values-from-a-spinner-to-sqlite-on-my-case